# TypeError: Unexpected keyword argument passed to optimizer: name

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to load a trained keras model. The training was done in Google Colaboratory, and I`m trying to load it on my computer, but an error occurs.

Keras version  - 2.2.4

Tensorflow version - 1.14.0

These versions match for my computer and Colab.

I tried to make h5py versions matching, but after downgrading it on my computer, Tensorflow stopped working as a whole, therefor I undid that.

How can I fix this?

```
import os
from tensorflow.python.keras import models
import UNet3Deep as UNet

working_dir = os.path.join('C:', os.sep, 'Users', 'Peteris.Zvejnieks', 'Data')
model_path = os.path.join(working_dir, 'tmp', 'real_deal.hdf5')
img_shape = (512, 512, 1) 

model = UNet.gib_model(img_shape)
models.load_model(model_path)
```

The error message:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-14-7e079df22f50>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/Peteris.Zvejnieks/Data/model_tester.py', wdir='C:/Users/Peteris.Zvejnieks/Data')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_build_env\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_build_env\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Peteris.Zvejnieks/Data/model_tester.py", line 37, in <module>
models.load_model(model_path)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_build_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\saving.py", line 249, in load_model
optimizer_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_build_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\optimizers.py", line 838, in deserialize
printable_module_name='optimizer')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_build_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 194, in deserialize_keras_object
return cls.from_config(cls_config)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_build_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\optimizers.py", line 159, in from_config
return cls(**config)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_build_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\optimizers.py", line 471, in __init__
super(Adam, self).__init__(**kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_build_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\optimizers.py", line 68, in __init__
'passed to optimizer: ' + str(k))

TypeError: Unexpected keyword argument passed to optimizer: name
```

Comment: Did you train the model using tf.keras or keras?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro tf.keras. I alredy fixed it myself, had to define optimizer before compiling.

Comment: @Peter how did you define it before compiling? can you add your solution to be useable by other users? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mohammad Sorry to anwser so late. I had to pass in custom loss functions of my of and compile boolean as follows `model = models.load_model(loadpath, custom_objects={'wce_dice_loss': wce_dice_loss, ...}, compile = False)` and then define the optimizer `adam = optimizers.Adam(...)`, after both of those steps, the model can be compiled - `model.compile(optimizer = adam, loss = wce_dice_loss, metrics = [...])`